# What is _UITemporaryLayoutWidth and why does it break my constraints?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a storyboard with Autolayout and Size Classes. Pretty complicated layout, and unfortunately I can't really pin down how to reproduce the problem in a new project.
But the view in question is pinned to the left and right edge of the screen with a constraint that has 750 priority (i.e. `|-(0@750)-[myView]-(0@750)-|`, additionally it *has a greater or equal* than constraint with a priority of 1000 (i.e. `|-(>=0)-[myView]-(>=0)-|`). That is done to limit the width on an iPad, so there is a width constraint of `width <= 600 @1000`, and a *center horizontal in container* constraint as well. On top of that the view has a aspect ratio constraint of 3:1. As I said, rather complicated.

Interface Builder doesn't show any problems with the constraints. The Xcode layout preview renders correct for all devices.

When I run the app iOS tells me that it has conflicting constraints.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd72853ff80 DMXKit.DipSwitchAssembly:0x7fd72990d0e0.width == 3*DMXKit.DipSwitchAssembly:0x7fd72990d0e0.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd728574e50 '_UITemporaryLayoutWidth' H:[DMXKit.DipSwitchAssembly:0x7fd72990d0e0(400)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd72856e9c0 V:[DMXKit.DipSwitchAssembly:0x7fd72990d0e0(133)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffb19798000 DMXKit.DipSwitchAssembly:0x7ffb1979a000.width == 3*DMXKit.DipSwitchAssembly:0x7ffb1979a000.height>
```

This is repeated a couple of times, with the exact same (i.e. same pointer) constraints. That is strange as well, looks like the constraint isn't really broken. When run, the app looks 100% correct. When I look at the app in the Xcode view debugger, the constraint with the address `0x7ffb19798000` is still there, so it was never broken.

Where does the `_UITemporaryLayoutWidth` constaint comes from? Obviously I didn't add it. Google doesn't spit out anything useful about `_UITemporaryLayoutWidth`. Did anyone encounter a problem like this?

Comment: I have a lot of these warnings in the log as well. Although, it doesn't seem to break my layout. I wonder where these `_UITemporaryLayoutWidth`s come from.

Answer (score 92):

So, I'm not sure if this helps you with your problem since it sounds like you're building your layout in IB, but here's an issue that I just ran into that may help others that google search for `_UITemporaryLayoutWidth`.

My scenario was that I was adding auto layout constraints during init and was accidentally triggering a `layoutIfNeeded` before adding the view to the view hierarchy (modifying a buttons edge insets triggers layout).  It looks like the system adds these temporary constraints and (I assume?) removes them after the view is added to the hierarchy.  The temp constraints set `0` dimensions (in my case) which can fail if you, for example, set specific constraint constant values in your layout (e.g., you want `16px` between these buttons but there's `0 space in that dimension...)

**Update:** Investigated a little more and found that the temporary constraint seems to correspond to the frame that you use to initialize the parent view.  In my case, the frame I used was size `0x0`, so the temp constraint evaluated relative to `0x0` size, thus failing.  Verified that if I init with a `5x5` frame then I see the same error with `_UITemporaryLayoutWidth(5)` constraint.  The other thing that I've noticed is that the constraint seems to be added and removed during the layout evaluation - if I break right before I trigger the layout and analyze the constraints then I don't see the temp constraints.  I also don't see the constraints after the error, so I suspect they synthesize the temp constraints, add them, solve, then remove them.

**Update 2:** Ok, maybe this is TMI but this might be of some use to someone.  My current thought is that these temp constraints are a peek into how the system handles mixed frame manipulation and auto layout within a single view hierarchy.  In my case, my view had no parent and had no constraints defining its size, but it did have a zero frame which meant the system assumed that's the size it should use when solving the layout.  My thought is that the system synthesizes these temp constraints for views that have their frames set explicitly to solve the rest of the system as it's traversing the hierarchy.

**Update 3:** So, I ran into this problem again and wanted to share a little more info.  My scenario was that I was trying to essentially measure views that had no parent using the `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:` method.  **Long story short, I had to call `layoutIfNeeded` on the view before measuring it - this is where I run into the conflict with the temp constraints since the view doesn't have a superview.**  The temp constraint constants (the dimensions) do correspond to whatever frame is set on the view without a superview - I think this makes sense (though, setting a frame on a view that you're going to be using with auto layout seems odd...)  I was able to get around the temp constraint issue by saying - if the view doesn't have a superview then add it to a temporary superview, measure it, and remove it from the temporary superview.  Hope this is useful.

Comment: ..."accidentally triggering a 'layoutIfNeeded' before adding the view to the view hierarchy" -- Thanks for that.

Comment: Traveler, the answer you seek is summarised by Adama in the comment above.

Comment: Happened to me when a view didn't had a superview yet but the subviews would have a complex layout using AutoLayout.

Comment: It took me 4 hours to debug the constraints until I saw the @Adama's comment.

Comment: In my case I just had to add default images to title-less buttons in the xib for the exception to go away

Comment: Thanks for sharing your journey! Just like @Adama hand picked haha that's the reason for this issue in most cases and helps you track down the problem "layoutIfNeeded before adding the view to the view hierarchy" 

Answer (score 22):

As mentioned above the temporary constraints appear to be set on views that don't have a parent view. I found that ensuring `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is `false` on the top level view removed the temporary constraints. As:

```swift
topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Comment: I did not need to set this flag on the superview - merely adding it was enough. This is in unit tests.

Answer (score 16):

I my case, the problem was the following:

I created a `UIButton`.
I set its width and height constraints.
I added the button to its superview.
I set its leading and top layout constraints to the superview.

This created the error "`Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints`" and one of the conflicting constraints was `_UITemporaryLayoutHeight`.

When I added the button to its superview **before** setting its width and height constraints, the error was gone.

Answer (score 9):

In my situation , I got this UITemporaryLayoutWidth conflict in this situation only

1. i create a view with [UIView new] , and i did not add it to any
   superview
2. then  i create a width constraint to this view just be created
3. invoke layoutIfNeeded to this view immediately,and the conflict
   happens

so the way to eliminate this error is simple : don't call layoutIfNeeded to it self before added to some superview

Answer (score 5):

I faced this issue when I added my constraints with layout-margins anchors of a view. When I changed the constraints from layout-margins anchors to top, bottom, leading, trailing anchors of the view, the error vanished.

I was creating my superview with `.zero` rect.

But since I needed to incorporate margins of the view I had to do a little hack. I changed the priority of my constraints.

I was getting temporary width and temporary height errors. So I lowered the priority of one constraint along horizontal axis and one constraint along vertical axis (top and trailing constraints in this case):

```
    let topConstraint = stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor)
    topConstraint.priority = .init(rawValue: 999.0)
    topConstraint.isActive = true

    let trailingConstraint = stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor)
    trailingConstraint.priority = .init(rawValue: 999.0)
    trailingConstraint.isActive = true
```

The reason for this is that since I initialize my view with .zero rect iOS automatically adds the temporary width and height constraints. At this time if we add other constraints with high priority, it will break generating the error logs.

Lowering the priority fixes the breaking constraints and when the temporary constraints are removed, our view will get its right shape.

Comment: To avoid this error, set the following atribute to false of your UIView. 
```translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false```

It will not create the _UITemporaryLayoutWidths.

Answer (score 4):

Spent a couple of hours on this problem today. I was setting the contentMode of my UIButton imageView immediately after initialising the element, which seemed to force a layout before I had set up the constraints in my top level class (Which included constraining the height/width).

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick addition to the comments above, the simple solution that worked for me was to change the order in which my constraints were being created.  I was programmatically creating constraints on both views and superviews - but I was doing the views before the superviews.  So I swapped it around so that the superview constraints went first, then the subviews had their constraints added, and this meant that there was no longer call for the _UITemporaryLayoutWidth, and so the constraint issues went away.

Comment: Why not just create all constraints in didMoveToSuperview()?

Answer (score 2):

A different approach worked for me.

I am creating all my views programmatically and am setting the initial frame of the top-level view (as in the one that goes to the `view` property of `UIViewController`) and its subviews to `CGRect.zero`. The generated warnings looked something like this:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280ebf200 UIStackView:0x136151380.width == UILayoutGuide:0x28140e3e0'UIScrollView-frameLayoutGuide'.width - 16   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280ddee40 '_UITemporaryLayoutWidth' MyApp.SearchFilterView:0x1316a8000.width == 0   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d4b480 'UIScrollView-frameLayoutGuide-width' UILayoutGuide:0x28140e3e0'UIScrollView-frameLayoutGuide'.width == MyApp.SearchFilterView:0x1316a8000.width   (active)>"
```

You will notice from the second line that `_UITemporaryLayoutWidth` is initially being set to zero.

I've wrestled with giving some of the subviews minimum width constraints, but only *giving the top-level view a non-zero frame* removed all Auto Layout warnings involving `_UITemporaryLayoutWidth`. I specifically used `UIScreen.main.bounds`.

```
class SearchFilterView {
  
  init( ... ) {
    // Instantiate properties here...
    super.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My UITemporaryLayoutWidth Issue was I was creating buttons programmatically and the tempWidth constraint would be around 0.1 off my width constraint. (Though annoyingly this only happened when creating buttons in one of the multiple ways I created buttons)

The issue was I was using .adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true for the button title.

I commented out that line and it went away.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is the 3:1 aspect ratio. If I change it to something else it works, I now use `4:1.4`, which works. I don't know why, but it works.

I don't know a lot about the internals of auto layout, but I think, the problem is the order how the layout engine wants to fulfill the constraints. Size classes might be the reason why the temporary width constraint is added.

The unsatisfiable constraints don't appear to be a real problem because it looks like they are unsatisfiable only temporarily. It's just a couple lines of log that appear each time the view is created.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is adding constraint to a view before adding it as subview to another view. If you assign constraints when there is no superview it automatically adds `_TemporaryLayout` constraints.To prevent that make `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` false.

In my case I was adding a view controller as another view controllers child. Even I set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntroConstraints` flag to false from where I add it to parent view controller the warnings were still there.

Then I found `loadView` method of childViewController called when the view of childViewController is first called. Therefore it does not work when you set autoresizing flag outside of the childViewController since it would already set their constraints.

ParentViewController

```
let childViewController = CustomViewController()
//childViewController.view.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false 
// This does not work since before this line executes loadView 

parentViewController.addChild(childViewController)
parentViewController.view.addSubview(childViewContoller.view) 
// `childViewContoller.view` triggers loadView method of childViewController
// It sets up constraints before adding as subview.
```

solution is making `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` false in childViewController

```
override func loadView() {

     super.loadView() // If you used storyboard call this to set those views
     // view = UIView() // call this if you layout views programatically 
    view.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this when I created a view and inadvertently animated one of its properties before it was presented.